# how to use chosen without search and still enable user to key in and auto jump to option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-chosen

In normal select elements, say for dates which have options from 01-31, you can press the key `12` and the select element auto selects the option `12`.

I want to do the same for a chosen plugin enabled select element. I have disabled the search option.

I know disabling the search while using chosen with single select defeats the purposes of using chosen, but I had to use it because we wanted the look and feel of all our selects to be consistent.

We have some select elements that do use the chosen as designed with search functions and allowing multiple selects.

So in the case of single select, disabled search chosen plugins, how do we have the ability to allow users to type and then the selected option auto jumps to the closest option?

Comment: why not just use a standard `select` tag? Most browsers will allow a user to type in an option's text.

Comment: As far as I'm aware - there is no way to do this. Its due to the way Chosen tweaks the SELECT box, into divs etc. If you inspect the element in Firebug, you will see the SELECT box remains - but there is a new div below it (which holds all the *chosen* contents). Due to this, you no longer have the standard way to type and get taken to the respective place in the SELECT box. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!